# Delete lists in list of lists that contain specific item in specific position

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists, which is called `listByLine`.

```
[['ACmerged_contig_24664', '379', '.', 'G', 'A', '4.38466', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=36', 'GT:PL', '1/1:32,3,0'], ['ACmerged_contig_24664', '380', '.', 'C', '.', '66', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=2;DP4=0,1,0,0;MQ=36', 'GT', '0/0'], ['ACmerged_contig_24664', '381', '.', 'T', '.', '66', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=2;DP4=0,1,0,0;MQ=36', 'GT', '0/0'], ['ACmerged_contig_24664', '382', '.', 'C', '.', '66', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=2;DP4=0,1,0,0;MQ=36', 'GT', '0/0'], ['ACmerged_contig_24664', '383', '.', 'G', 'A', '7.30814', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=36', 'GT:PL', '1/1:36,3,0']]
```

I want to delete lists in this list that have `'.'` in the 5th place in the list.

I have tried this code:

```
for list in listByLine:
    if list[5] == '.':
        listByLine.remove(list)
```

This code does not remove any of the lists from by list of list though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new list:

```
lst = [['ACmerged_contig_24664', '379', '.', 'G', 'A', '4.38466', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=36', 'GT:PL', '1/1:32,3,0'],
       ['ACmerged_contig_24664', '380', '.', 'C', '.', '66', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=2;DP4=0,1,0,0;MQ=36', 'GT', '0/0'],
       ['ACmerged_contig_24664', '381', '.', 'T', '.', '66', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=2;DP4=0,1,0,0;MQ=36', 'GT', '0/0'],
       ['ACmerged_contig_24664', '382', '.', 'C', '.', '66', '.', 'DP=1;MQ0F=0;AN=2;DP4=0,1,0,0;MQ=36', 'GT', '0/0'],
       ['ACmerged_contig_24664', '383', '.', 'G', 'A', '7.30814', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=36', 'GT:PL', '1/1:36,3,0'],
       ['x', 'y', 'z']]

new_lst = [sublist
           for sublist in lst
           for length in [len(sublist)]
           if ((length < 5) or (length >= 5 and not sublist[4] == '.'))]
print(new_lst)
```

A couple of notes: the *fifth* element is referred to as `lst[4]` and the above code checks the length - shorter lists are simply kept. Additionally, do not call your variables `list`.

Answer (score 1):

The lists in python count elements starting from 0. In your code above there is no sublist that contain `'.'` as it's fifth element. If you print out every fifth element you will get something like:

```
4.38466
66
66
66
7.30814
```

But if you instead change your code to check every fourth element of the list to be equal to `'.'` - it will work as expected, e.g. code

```
for l in listByLine:
  if l[4] == '.':
    listByLine.remove(l)

print(listByLine)
```

will produce output with 3 sublists only